# How do I run a terminal script when mounting a specific disk?

Tags: usb, high-sierra

I have rsync set up, I have set up rsync as a UNIX executable and named the bash script as 'backup' and I saved it to /usr/local/bin so whenever I type `backup` in terminal it would do a backup to my external disk. But I want it setup in such a way whenever I plug in that drive it would run that bash script. I have already googled this but it doesn't work with High Sierra.

Comment: What have you Googled that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Ok as per all the suggestions the users gave [I googled](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/18238/launchd-startonmount-doesn-t-behave-as-expected) and found a nice .plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.company.popup</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/backup</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartOnMount</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>`
```

I have put this code under ~/Library/LaunchAgents and runs at login.Thanks for all your replies again it helped me find a better code.